# What are the intermediate steps in changing $(25-3\sqrt{69})^{1/3}$ to $\frac{2^{2/3}}{(25+3\sqrt{69})^{1/3}} $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

I was messing with WolframAlpha trying to simplify a function, and I noticed that $$(25-3\sqrt{69})^{1/3}$$ somehow has the alternate form of: 
$$
\frac{2^{2/3}}{(25+3\sqrt{69})^{1/3}}
$$

I tried manipulating it on my own with my calculus-level education, but I couldn't figure out where that 2 came from or how a sign change within the radical can occur in like this.

Here's the [link to WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2825%20-%203%20sqrt%2869%29%29%5E%281%2F3%29) showing what my input was; any guidance in this problem would be very appreciated!

Comment: Calculus-level education and still couldn't?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I forgot that you can effectively bypass the exponent and multiply what's inside two multiplied terms if both of their exponents are the same... I was really overthinking this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They've just multiplied and divided by $(25+3\sqrt{69})^{1/3}$.

So, $(25-3\sqrt{69})^{1/3}\cdot(25+3\sqrt{69})^{1/3} = (625 - 9(69))^{1/3} = 4^{1/3} = 2^{2/3}$